# getting src from video tag using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to get the link of video on this page https://in.news.yahoo.com/video/jitendra-singh-visits-manipur-militants-051500244.html. I tried in multiple way using selenium but no luck. Can someone point what I am doing wrong

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
def getVideoTrend(self, "https://in.news.yahoo.com/video/jitendra-singh-visits-manipur-militants-051500244.html"):
    driver.get(url)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_class_name('mediavideoplayervppca'))
    video_trend = []
    #s = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('video.yvp-html5-video') #this also does not help
    s = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="yui_3_9_1_1_1434089562443_964"]')
    print s
    print s.get_attribute('src')
```

Please open link in chrome to see the page element

Comment: The ID of the that element is always changing so you won't able to get it. Just refresh the page and inspect the element again, it will has a different ID. In the other hand the video is get played in a Flash Applet and it doesn't include the source of the video.

Comment: @peety: if you see in chrome, you would be able to see video tag and url, id  value would be changing though

Comment: There is no `video` tag on the page, this is a flash player object.

Answer (score 0):

In that given URL you have only one video tag. So you can get src by using tagName.

something like this:

```
    By byLocator = By.tagName("video");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions
            .presenceOfElementLocated(byLocator));
    WebElement findElement = driver.findElement(byLocator);
    System.out.println("Src file : " + findElement.getAttribute("src"));
```

Comment: the same thing I have implemented, could you get video url using this? I guess you wrote in java, mine was same in python

Comment: yah..i'm getting video url in java.

Comment: Do you have find_element_by_tagName() method?? in python